# php mysql insert exact number of times

Tags: php, mysql

Could not find a working solution yet.. Looking for help to make php insert certain number of rows according to number i provide in the form i.e 7.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input name="number" type="text" value="">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Go">
</form>
```

SO in this form i want to input numeric value and once submitted i want to repeat insertion exact number of times as i have set in form (7 times in this case)

```
INSERT INTO table (value1, value2) VALUES ('Created', '".date("H:i:s")."')
```

What should be the solution?

Comment: You have the number X? So you need X queris.

Comment: Issue the insert in a loop going from 1 to number.

Comment: Ok so use function and/or loop to execute insert query no of times.

Comment: @Ties The question is tagged with "php" so I'm assuming he does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your insert query in loop from 1 to number

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['number']) && is_numeric($_POST['number']) && $_POST['number']!='' && $_POST['number']>0)
{
    for($i=1;$i<=$_POST['number'];$i++)
    {
       // your insert query here..
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @AlbusOne this is not efficient as it performs multiple queries. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
<?php
$number=$_POST['number'];
if($number != "" && $number != '0'){
    while(1 <= $number)
    {
        //inser code..INSERT INTO table (value1, value2) VALUES ('Created', '".date("H:i:s")."')
        $number--;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will perform multiple queries, which is not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stated the method to be 'post' on the form, you can obtain the $_POST information for the number submitted, store it into a variable, then have a loop to repeat the operation for the amount of times stated in that variable.

```
<?php

$AmountToInsert = $_POST['number'];

if($AmountToInsert > 0)
{
    for($index=1; $index<=$AmountToInsert; $index++)
    {
       // Execute your query/code here
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you could do this:

```
$number = (number)$_GET['number'] ?: 1;
$value = "('Created', '" . date("H:i:s") . "')";

// Creating multiple inputs like: (valueA1, valueA2), (valueB1, valueB2), ...
$values = implode(',', array_fill(0, $number, $value));

$query = 'INSERT INTO table (value1, value2) VALUES ' . $values; 

// Run query etc...
```

### Performance

With this method you will only query the database once, which will be faster and more scalable.